# NOT IN statement or what to use in this case?

Tags: postgresql

I need to delete each row in `fabricante_producto_solicitud` (fps from now on) table if `fps.id` has not relation (NOT IN) `fabricante_modelo_marca_producto` (fmmp from now on).

Since my input will be an array of values (fps.id) as for example:

```
array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

How, if it's possible, using NOT IN I can know which `fps.id` is on `fmmp` table and which not? In this case fps.id aren't in `fmmp` can be deleted the existent not. Any advice or any other way to achieve this?

This is the model (just for info purposes)

**Doing some tests:**

Based on the answer by the user I modified a bit the original query and comes with this:

```
DELETE
FROM
    negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud
WHERE
    negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            negocio.fabricante_modelo_marca_producto.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
        FROM
            negocio.fabricante_modelo_marca_producto
    )
AND negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.id = :someParameter;
```

Can I pass an array as `:someParameter` value or I need to iterate for the values and execute the query several times?

[image]

Comment: This is a left-anti-join. You can do it with a `DELETE ... FROM` too, with a self-join.

Comment: @CraigRinger can you share your suggestion? Is more efficient than the one by __Miguel__?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM fps WHERE fps.id NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT fps_id FROM fmmp)
```

The sub query should find a list of fps ids that are being referred to, so you can delete any fps entries that are not in that list.

Comment: can you take a look to the edit I made based on your answer?

Comment: Remember to consider `NULL`.

Comment: What you mean with _consider NULL_? Can you improve the answer?

Comment: @ReynierPM `NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)` does not do what you might expect it to, which is a well known problem. You should generally have a `WHERE fps_id IS NOT NULL` constraint on the inner query if you're using `NOT IN` with a subquery. See mailing list discussion, Google, etc for *many* relevant examples and discussions.